# i have to Create Folder in bin-debug and then create and write in text file in it

Tags: c#

i wrote this code , it ctreates folder named "Fitness50"  each time but the text file is not created.i want to create textfile within this folder and then save values of an arraylist.
so for i have tried this

```
DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:");
ParentFolderName1 = "Fittness50";
myDir.CreateSubdirectory(ParentFolderName1);
myDir = new DirectoryInfo(ParentFolderName1);
ParentFolderName1 = "Fittness50";
myDir.CreateSubdirectory(ParentFolderName1);



FileName1 = "./" + "" + ParentFolderName1 + "" + "/" + "Fittness10" + "" + "" + PopulationID + "" + ".txt";

FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(FileName1, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter SW2 = new StreamWriter(fs2);

for (i = 0; i < AlTargetData.Count; i++)
{
      SW2.WriteLine(AlTargetData[i]);

}

AlTargetData.Clear();

SW2.Close();
fs2.Close();
```

Comment: "text file is not created", are you getting any errors that are preventing the file from being created?

Comment: Check `AlTargetData.Count` to make sure it is not 0. If you never enter that loop to call `SW2.WriteLine(AlTargetData[I]);` then I don't think any file would be created, but I'm not 100% sure that the file isn't created when you instantiate the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: it looks like you're creating a folder on `E:`, not in `bin/debug`. Instead of combining strings for the file location, use `Path.Combine`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all, `/` is not the preferred directory separator on Windows, but `\` is. Just because `/` happens to work, there's no reason to use it. Secondly, you're not creating the `Fittness10` folder at all, but you're creating `Fittness50` twice. And third, you're not writing the file to the folders you create, but to the current working directory `.`.

Your code (or at least what I understand you want to achieve) can be shortened significantly to this:

```
string path = @"E:\Fittness50\Fittness10";
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

string fileName = Path.Combine(path, String.Format("{0}.txt", PopulationID));
File.WriteAllText(fileName, String.Join(Environment.NewLine, AlTargetData));
```

Please note that you should *not* consider writing to `bin\debug`. There will be no `bin\debug` on the end-user's machine. If the user installs your application, it will be most probably be installed in the `Program Files` folder, which your application won't be allowed to write to. Instead, consider writing to a common location, like the ones you can chose from in `Environment.GetFolderPath`.

Comment: FYI you *can* use `/` in a path string, Windows will handle it just fine.

Comment: Concerning writing to the program folder: that depends. I often make small tools without any kind of installer, using a simple ini config file in the program's folder. I don't expect for a second that anyone will unpack it in Program Files. For bigger stuff though, yeah, use the user folders.

Comment: You could, but why should you? Windows defines the path separator as "\". The fact that it happens to handle "/" too, does not mean you should use it.

Comment: @Nyerguds I did not say that :-) If you just unpack a tool somewhere, it may (or may not) be allowed to write to its folder. But *if* you install it in `Program Files`, it will very surely *not* be allowed to write to its own folder.

Comment: I agree with that. I'm just saying, stating that '/' isn't valid and that you *have* to use '\' is incorrect. Call me pedantic I guess.

Comment: @DrewJordan To be most pedantic you'd have to vote against hardcoding paths in the first place - the application might run on Linux with Mono, which doesn't even know what `E:\` is :D

Comment: To be perfectly safe, just use the thing that exists for it; `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`.

Comment: @Nyerguds ... or `Path.Combine`, which does it right, too.

Comment: @Nyerguds Oh, and why do you use `ini` files when .NET comes with such handy application/user configuration files that don't require you to code a single line? :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Yup, though that's a function call, and it only takes two arguments; for building a tree of hardcoded folders, it's not really advised.

Comment: @Nyerguds Wrong, it takes an open list of parameters, so you *can* write `string path = Path.Combine("E:", "Fittness50", "Fittness10", "FileName.txt");`

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Because 1. I like my configs to be human-readable, and easily human-editable, and xml isn't too fit for that, and 2. I've got this neat ini reading library which I originally wrote for reading an old game's config files, and I just keep reusing it ;)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I mostly (still) program on 3.5, though, and that one doesn't have that overload.

Comment: On the original subject: all path related functions in .net seem to be fit for handling urls as well as local paths, hence why they all accept '/' too.

Comment: @Nyerguds Well, you're right about 3.5 not having this. I disagree with your use of `ini` files, but that's not the topic here :-D About URLs: Then, please, use a proper `file://` URL and not just some path.